# AWS Elasticbeanstalk Returns HTTP 503 For HTTPS Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently had to update my SSL certificate for my AWS Elasticbeanstalk. After the SSL certificate was updated, it started returning HTTP 503 error if I use HTTPS. It used to work fine earlier with HTTPS.

Comment: HTTP 503: Service Unavailable
`The target groups for the load balancer have no registered targets.` double check the target and the port mapping

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that when I changed my SSL certificate, the HTTPS out port 443 was some how mapped to inbound 443 port instead of port 80. All communication between load balancer and EC2 happens on HTTP on port 80. The load balancer which takes requests from external internet takes the HTTPS on port 443. So ensure the internal port mapping is 80 with HTTP and external is 443 with HTTPS